# Does ktor provide main-safe suspending functions like retrofit and room

Tags: android, ktor

I'm using ktor in my android project and I have experience in using coroutines with retrofit and room. So my question is like retrofit and room does ktor provide main-safe suspending function, by this I mean like in retrofit and room I don't have to use blocking code using `withContext(Dispatchers.{some dispatcher})` to make network requests to ensure main safety, I just simply make a suspend function in my repository and use them through a coroutine launched in ViewModel(which is basically a class used to hold data for UI controllers).

In retrofit:

```
suspend fun refreshTitle(){
        try {
            mainNetwork.fetchNextTitle()
            titleDao.insertTitle(Title(result))
        } catch (cause: Throwable) {
            throw TitleRefreshError("Unable to refresh title", cause)
        }
    }

interface MainNetwork {
    @GET("some_path")
    suspend fun fetchNextTitle(): String
}
```

So in retrofit version you can see I simply made `suspend fun fetchNextTitle()` a suspend function and directly called it in `suspend fun refreshTitle()` which is a method of repository because retrofit is taking care of main safety for networking request.

Now in ktor,

```
class MainNetwork(private val httpClient: HttpClient) {
        suspend fun fetchNextTitle(): String {
            return httpClient.get(path = "some_path")
        }
}
```

So, if I replace the retrofit service with ktor and directly use it from `mainNetwork.fetchNextTitle()` in the `suspend fun refreshTitle()` is ktor going to provide main safety by itself or I have to use `withContext(Dispatchers.${some_dispatcher_other_than_main})` to call the `suspend fun fetchNextTitle()` to ensure main safety from the networking part.

Comment: Could you please add a code example to your question to better illustrate your point?

Comment: The quick answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I edited the question, I think it almost explains my problem and thanks for the answer but can you take a look at the edit question just in case I explained my problem in wrong way.

Comment: The answer is still yes :)

Comment: Okay, thanks @AlekseiTirman for helping:).